# BeautifulSoup unsuccessful request

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I'm using urlopen to extract data from a list of websites right now but keep running in problems with unsuccessful requests. Can anyone help me with it?

## I save the website as HTML file

```
path = "/Users/runyao/Downloads/The Proposition 65 List | OEHHA.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path), "html.parser")
list = []
pattern = "(chemicals)+([a-z0-9-])"
for counter in range(1,852):
    temp = str(soup.find_all('option')[counter])
    temptext = temp.replace("\n","/")
    temptext = temptext.replace('"',"/")
    temptext = temptext.replace(">","")
    templist = temptext.split("/")
    list.append(templist[-4])
url = 'https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/'+ list[1] + '/'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
    the_page = response.read()

import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
​
url = "https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/"+ list[1] 
headers = {}
headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)   AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")
print(respData)



<html>
<head>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></head></html>
```

Comment: can you be more specific ? ...I mean..can you show us your code an the error?

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, it would be more helpful to provide the actual code snippet itself, including the actual full url you are using (so that we can try to make the same request potentially)

Comment: add more headers in your requests , open the console google chrome and then check network with all request ..convert curl to python

Comment: do you suggest me use google chrome instead of safari?

Answer (score 0):

And if you try adding more headers , like this....this work for me :

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'oehha.ca.gov',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9',
    'cookie': 'visid_incap_1712983=Dfo+CVLdTCSzMHcIXEgPSb1y7l0AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAetg/EHDkFJUigbIo4eaK4; incap_ses_532_1712983=dFrgDpkdqkYCF1u+mQxiB71y7l0AAAAAksMc42V5CJx6OdUZdeHflA==; has_js=1; _ga=GA1.2.626207180.1575908117; _gid=GA1.2.512657448.1575908117; __utma=158387685.626207180.1575908117.1575908117.1575908117.1; __utmc=158387685; __utmz=158387685.1575908117.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)^|utmccn=(direct)^|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmt_b=1; _aeaid=5e12b9d6-0171-4fde-8ccf-1bba809a1bb2; aeatstartmessage=true; __utmb=158387685.4.10.1575908117',
    'if-none-match': '^\\^1575853039-1^\\^',
}

response = requests.get('https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/abiraterone-acetate', headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

UPDATE:I have updated the code using urllib , probably have problems because they have blocked the IP from where you make the requests.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = "https://oehha.ca.gov/chemicals/abiraterone-acetate"
# headers = {}
# headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)   AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36',
    'cookie': 'visid_incap_1712983=Dfo+CVLdTCSzMHcIXEgPSb1y7l0AAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAetg/EHDkFJUigbIo4eaK4; incap_ses_532_1712983=dFrgDpkdqkYCF1u+mQxiB71y7l0AAAAAksMc42V5CJx6OdUZdeHflA==; has_js=1; _ga=GA1.2.626207180.1575908117; _gid=GA1.2.512657448.1575908117; __utma=158387685.626207180.1575908117.1575908117.1575908117.1; __utmc=158387685; __utmz=158387685.1575908117.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)^|utmccn=(direct)^|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1; __utmt_b=1; _aeaid=5e12b9d6-0171-4fde-8ccf-1bba809a1bb2; aeatstartmessage=true; __utmb=158387685.4.10.1575908117',
}
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=None, headers = headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = BeautifulSoup(resp,"html.parser",from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
print(respData)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: hi, it still does not work for me. I keep getting: b'<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">\r\n<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">\r\n</script>\r\n<body>\r\n</body></html>'

Comment: with the same code that did i give you ??..is rare because in my case I can access without problem

Comment: can you give a url exact? ...I mean without variable list[1]

Comment: yes , with urllib I have the same problem ..but there is not posible to use requests like above??

Comment: yes. I tried the code above, it still does not allow me to extract the information